# Making script re-useable, i.e not keep repeating it?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a better way of doing this in js? Or more so, how would I do this better in js?
So I don't have 3 scripts basically the same.

Thank you for any help in advance

```
<label for="img1">Image 1:</label>
<input type="file" id="img1" name="img1" />
<img id="image1"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("img1").onchange = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("image1").src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    };
</script>

<label for="img2" >Image 2:</label>
<input type="file" id="img2" name="img2" />
<img id="image2"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("img2").onchange = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("image2").src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    };
</script>

<label for="img3">Image 3:</label>
<input type="file" id="img3" name="img3" />
<img id="image3"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("img3").onchange = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("image3").src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    };
</script>
```

Trying to explain myself a little better.
For example in python, loop through something and use the i in the function.

```
gg = ("a", "q", "f", "4", "f", "h")
for i in range(len(gg)):
    print ('thing'+str(i))
```

Comment: For example in python

g = ("1", "2", "3", "4")
for i in gg:
    print ('thing'+i)

Comment: You could create a Javascript function accepting two arguments, the input id and the image id respectively: `var addImageLoader = function(inputId, imageId) { ... }` and then refer to these variables within your `getElementById` calls. Note: it could be possible that you need to do some juggling with `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<label for="img1">Image 1:</label>
<input type="file" id="img1" name="img1" />
<img id="image1"/>
<label for="main_img">Image 2:</label>
<input type="file" id="img2" name="img2" />
<img id="image2"/>
<label for="main_img">Image 3:</label>
<input type="file" id="img3" name="img3" />
<img id="image3"/>
<script>
imgOnChange('img1','image1');
imgOnChange('img2','image2');
imgOnChange('img3','image3');
function imgOnChange(imgId, imageId) {
    document.getElementById(imgId).onchange = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById(imageId).src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: I cut the code down so it wasn't miles long. I changed the ids and fors but missed the first one